# Query taking too long on a simple select

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql

I have a Laravel backend application that use a multi-tenant database using Postgres where every tenant has a SCHEMA. So I have 2 tables that are **bra_product and bra_file**, both have a JOIN that is from a specific schema let's call it "tenant10".

I have 2500 schemas each has both columns and I create a schema called MASTER where all tables from schemas INHERIT from that.

So **master.bra_product** has all the data from all products from all schemas, so this simple QUERY:

```
$size = count($productList);
$counter = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $counter++;
    $productList[$i]->srcimglist = $this->mdFile->getMasterImageByProduct($productList[$i]);
}
dd($productList);
return $productList;
```

I take here a list of 20 products that I make a loop to take the image list of each, that will execute this:

```
public function getMasterImageByProduct($product) {
    return DB::select("SELECT bra_f.*
                          FROM master.bra_file bra_f
                          WHERE bra_f.product_id = :productId
                          AND bra_f.active = true
                          ORDER BY bra_f.order", ['productId' => $product->product_id]);

}
```

My master.bra_file has 12.500 rows, my query is taking me 40 seconds this is not normal and I don't know why.

Comment: I don't see how those 2500 schemas are of any relevance here. This is just about one table `master.bra_file` with 12500  rows for which a query takes way too long. That's all. Correct? Or is `master.bra_file` a *view* accessing tables in those other schemas?

Comment: master.bra_file is a father table that has 2.500 child schemas that have a table called bra_file that INHERIT from master.bra_file

Comment: master.bra_file is a table that has 12,058 it is correct, this table has this number because he is a father table from all bra_file tables from all schemas you understand?

Comment: Now I found something strange when I remove ORDER BY bra_f.order, my query now takes 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You may try creating another table to hold all child data and avoid inheritance.

Mirror the structure of bra_file into another "cache" table and update it automatically using triggers on INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE.